# Django {% static 'path' %} in javascript file

Tags: django

In my script.js:

```
pic.src = "/static/photos/1.jpg"; // This works
pic2.src = "{% static 'photos/1.jpg' %}" // Does not work
```

Why in the world this happens? Since in my home.html, the {% static 'path' %} works:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<script src="{% static 'script.js' %}"></script>  // This works
```

And is it {% load staticfiles %} or {% load static %} ? Both work for me, script.js is loaded.

Comment: Yes, because the html file is a template but the static files are not treated as such.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Simeon! So pic.src="static/photos/1.jpg" is the only way?

Comment: If you really wanted your javascript to be rendered from templates/views, you could easily do that. But it's probably not what you want. More likely, you want the bulk of your js to be static files and then to add view-specific code to the bottom of a template in a <script> element.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Since you are using django's template language you can **ONLY** do this within your template between `<script>` tags. In other words if you wished to use your `pic2.src` javascript variable in an **external** script then you would need to declare it between `<script>` tags like so

```
<script>
    var pic2.src = "{% static "photos/1.jpg" %}"
</script>
```

And then you could access it in your external scripts that you might load like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/my_external_script.js" %}"></script>
```

Regarding your question concerning `load static` and `load staticfiles` there is little distinction. Both act as a joiner for the `STATIC_URL` in your `settings.py` and the actual path to the file itself so both should work for your case. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/) for more info.

Comment: it is important to note that if you're using a cloud service to store static files (e.g. AWS S3), then there will be a significant difference between `load static` and `load staticfiles` which is something that got me a few times. `staticfiles` dynamically gets the correct backend where files are stored, while `static` just always uses the default. if you use `static` instead of `staticfiles` then your code will not work properly in aws.

Comment: Shouldn't these be surrounded with `{% filter escapejs %}...{% endfilter %}` ?

Comment: I'm not a web developer so this might seem trivial but is it a good idea to write JS code into the HTML, I know it's accepted but mixing the two of them together seems like it could lead to some difficulties in the long run for developers but also some security issues

Answer (score 20):

If you need many static (or media) url's in your `.js` files, this might be more convenient:

```
<script>
    var static_url = "{% get_static_prefix %}";
    var media_url = "{% get_media_prefix %}";
</script>
```

Then both url's are freely available in all javascript files.

Comment: this will cause an issue with collectstatic on deployment.

Comment: @NK What kind of issue?

Comment: I thought creating urls like this was causing the problem - that for any urls not created with {% static %} , the resources were not being collected. But I found later that the problem was something else, and these are possibly being collected in the postprocessing phase.

Comment: However, it will not enable cache-busting using Manifest-Storage on deployment, since you will have an unhashed reference.

Comment: Shouldn't these be surrounded with `{% filter escapejs %}...{% endfilter %}` ?

Answer (score 13):

You can assign the path in your template and then use it in your javascript file.

Template:

```
<script>
    var url = "{% static 'photos/1.jpg' %}";
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
pic2.src = url
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be surrounded with `{% filter escapejs %}...{% endfilter %}` ?

Answer (score 5):

Easy Workaround! :)

index.html

```
<input type="hidden" id="pic-src" value="{% static 'photos/1.jpg' %}">
```

script.js

```
var pic2.src = $('pic-src').val();
```