# Load Three JS model with gltf loader in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, three.js

I am trying to load a Three JS model in a Django(3.0.3) app on a local environment.

Template:

```
<script>
    var address_to_model ="{% static 'models/matilda/scene.gltf' %}"; // Pass this variable to .js file
</script>
<script src="{% static 'js/matilda.js' %}"></script>
```

matilda.js:

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader( );
loader.load( address_to_model, function ( gltf ) {
        scene.add( gltf.scene );
    }, undefined, function ( error ) {
        console.error( error );
} );
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
```

The page loads without any Django error and it shows the ThreeJS window which is working but the model is not loaded and in the Chrome error console, I get this error:

> GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/matilda/models/matilda/scene.gltf 404 (Not Found)

I think it should not check this URL because I do not resolve it in urls.py and there is nothing  in this address. It should load the model which is collected in the 'static/models/matilada' with **collectstatic** command.

I check these links but they do not help:
* [Django {% static 'path' %} in javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932983/django-static-path-in-javascript-file)
* [Correctly accessing django static files from external javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50566194/correctly-accessing-django-static-files-from-external-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1)
* [Django: External JS using framework doesn't load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419442/django-external-js-using-framework-doesnt-load?noredirect=1&lq=1)
* https://pypi.org/project/django-js-urls/

Answer (score 0):

You need to host the website on an IP address, that lets the threejs gltf model to load.