# Correctly accessing django static files from external javascript

Tags: angularjs, django, django-staticfiles

I've got a django application using AngularJS with a bunch of JavaScript and template files.

In my django template I can use the `{% static %}` tag to properly reference those files like so:

```
<script src="{% static "angular/myapp.app.js" %}"></script>
```

However, the external files themselves obviously [do not get resolved through django's templating framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932983/django-static-path-in-javascript-file) and so that's not an option. So what people most often do is just hard code the static path there:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
   // this works but is not ideal
   templateUrl: '/static/pages/some-angular-template.html',  
})
```

I have seen recommendations of loading `STATIC_URL` into javascript somewhere and using that to construct references. Something like this:

**Django template**:

```
var STATIC_URL = {{ STATIC_URL }};
function getStaticUrl(templatePath) {
  return STATIC_URL + templatePath;
}
```

**External JS**:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
   templateUrl: getStaticUrl('/pages/some-angular-template.html'),
})
```

This is a bit better, but still not perfect because it only handles the base path. If you want to use something like [`ManifestStaticFilesStorage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage) (which I do) then you still don't get the proper resolution of the file.

Is there any good solution to this problem? Options I am considering:

- Bootstrapping all necessary URLs into JS variables inside the django template
- Storing the urls in some hidden HTML markup using `data` tags (again via the django template)
- Creating an API to get the URLs (this seems bonkers and like it would be terrible performance-wise).

Just wondering if there's a standard practice or library that addresses this issue? I have run into this problem several times and never found a satisfactory solution.

Comment: This is especially tricky if using manifest storage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My current solution (which works fine if not the most elegant) is just creating a huge global dict of constants in the django template and then referencing them directly in JS.

**Django Template**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    NG_STATIC_FILES = {
       "HOME": "{% static '/pages/home.html' %}",
       "SOMETHING_ELSE": "{% static '/pages/some-angular-template.html' %}",
    };
</script>
```

**External JS**:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: NG_STATIC_FILES.SOMETHING_ELSE,
})
```

etc.

Comment: Was thinking of doing the same thing and then found your answer. Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: If you're going to do that it might be simpler to use the untranslated paths as the keys in the `NG_STATIC_FILES` dictionary. Then you can create a list of those paths and generate the dictionary by iterating over that list, assigning translated paths (values) to untranslated paths (keys).

Answer (score 1):

## Other option 1

Use your `getStaticUrl` function, but make it also append a query string like `?v=abc`, where `abc` is unique for every deployed version of your app, to bust caches. (For example, your html defines `window.ASSET_VERSION = 'abc'` and when you deploy a new version of your app then your html defines `window.ASSET_VERSION = 'xyz'`.)

Advantages:

- Don't need a huge global dict.

  - **Don't need to maintain it.**
  - Less knowledge about your app is visible to users who are looking for it (including malicious users) in one place (if that matters).
    Might save on server costs.

Disadvantages:

- During a deploy of a new version of the app, when a user visits the site, then their browser will receive new static assets and old html, and the mismatch may cause the user to experience bugs.
- If you use a CDN, like CloudFront, then you must configure it to include query strings in the cache key.
- Probably makes A/B testing impossible?
- When a new version of the app is deployed, the new static assets must be uploaded before the new html servers are deployed, or old static assets will erroneously be used by some of your users for a long time. (If a user visits your site during a deploy, their browser will receive new html and old static assets, will cache those old assets with the new query string, and will continue to use those old assets until the user manually clears the cache, the cached response expires, or the next deploy happens.)

## Other option 2

Similar to "Creating an API to get the URLs": Put a dictionary containing the URLs in a static json file and make your `getStaticUrl` function return a Promise that resolves to the requested url after it fetches the json file. Put a version id in the json file name or in a cache busting query string (see above) so that the json file can be cached.

Advantages:

- Performance might be better because the URL data is cached in the browser.
- Might save on server costs.

Disadvantages:

- All JavaScript that wants one of these URLs must by async. (Probably a deal breaker.)

  - Software engineers must spend more time (expensive).