# How to inject HTML code with static file reference to Django template

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a simple use case in which I need to dynamically add rows to a table in my HTML template. I am using the following javascript code to add this on a button click:

```
function add_row(){
   row_html = '<tr><td><img src="path/to/my/file.png"></td></tr>'
   $('#table-id').append(row_html);
}
```

The only problem is that the image is not being found. I have also tried using Django template language, doesn't work. One solution is defining the src in the script tag in my HTML template like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932983/django-static-path-in-javascript-file). However I am not sure this is the optimal approach.

What is the correct approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Have a look at the _last_ answer i.e. the [one by @tri.akki7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67727205/14991864) on your linked question. I find it to be the best out of all those answers (It doesn't render from Django into JavaScript), unfortunately it has the least upvotes :(. I do believe you will find it suitable after perhaps some minor adjustments? :) (the `input` tag can really be any other tag with a custom data-attribute)

Comment: What is the image path you are using? Do you have an example for that?

Comment: The image is in the app static files folder. I have tried using static/app/img/image.png and also app/img/image.png and also app/static/app/img/image.png . I am following Django name spacing conventions.