# How to pass Django template language variables to JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

The question is partially related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932983/django-static-path-in-javascript-file) here. In addition it should be noted that the notation used below is no safe. For more details see [this blog post](https://adamj.eu/tech/2022/10/06/how-to-safely-pass-data-to-javascript-in-a-django-template/).

---

I have a Django project that references multiple JS files. Initial the contents of those files were in the HTML but it slowly became too cluttered.

The problem is that inside these files I am referencing image files, which are used for creating button elements (in my case `easyButton` instances from Leaflet).

I am looking for a way to somehow fix these references. Note that I have called `collectstatic` and my HTML is using `{% load static %}` to load the static content. My JS files are also defined as Django template language variables themselves.

I am thinking of perhaps at least loading all the references to the static files inside the HTML and then using those inside my JS files.

Here is an example code:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/application/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    const TEST = {{ test }}; // The 'test' variable unwraps as "/home/user/.../img_default.png"
</script>
<!-- Try to use TEST inside setup.js -->
<script src="{% static 'setup.js' %}></script>
<script src="{% static 'main.js' %}></script>
```

where `setup.js` consists of function declarations that are called inside `main.js`, e.g.:

```
function add_misc_buttons() {
    var btn_create_log = L.easyButton("<img src='" + TEST + "' style='width: 32px; height: 32px;'/>", function (btn, map) {
        console.log("TODO Send debug information to the developer");

        window.location.href = "mailto:admin@example.com?body=THIS%20IS%20A%20TEST";
    });

    ...
}
```

with `TEST` being passed from the HTML file and populated by Django (a typical value would be something like `images/some_image.png`).

Needless to say this doesn't work. My `main.js` (where all the functions are called) doesn't really detect the existence of `TEST`. I even added a `console` log message to display the value but nothing shows. Is there some way to do this? I am no JS and Django expert by far. I know that variables in general are visible between tags (if declared in a correct order). But it appears this does not apply when using a mix.

Answer (score 0):

So not 100% sure if this will solve your issue -- but this is how I handle such setups:

```
# views.py

def render_post(request, id):

    # Get a qs and serialize
    qs_quotes_set = DailyQuotes.objects.all()
    qs_quotes = serializers.serialize("json", qs_quotes_set)

    # Create context
    ctx = {
        'qs_quotes': qs_quotes,
    }
    return render(request, 'board/post.html', ctx)
```

```
# post.html

...

<!-- Construct js object for daily quotes data -->

<script type="text/javascript">
 let daily_quotes = JSON.parse('{{ qs_quotes | safe }}')
</script>

...
```

```
# xy.js

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(daily_quotes)) {

  console.log('I am an entry of your Django queryset processed in the javascript file')
}
```

Note that in your html file the js object constructor needs to be before the js file that should use it. Also If I recall correctly there is a small section about this topic somewhere in the Django docs but can't seem to find it right now.

Comment: Is there a solution where no `queryset` is used? The data (icons) is not and imho doesn't make sense to be stored as a database entries. Do you have an alternative solution? (this one can also be left here since it is helpful in some situations). Even if I replace your `queryset` with a normal JSON string (visible in the HTML), I still cannot get it passed onto the JS file. I even wrote a simple function that is called inside a `<script/>` tag, while being defined inside a preceding JS file. I am missing some general knowledge on how JS inside tag interacts with JS inside separate file